# Fastest way to move 90 million files (270GB) between two NFS 1Gb/s folders

Tags: rsync, nfs

I need to move 90 million files from a NFS folder to a second NFS folder, both connections to NFS folder are using same eth0, which is 1Gb/s to the NFS servers, Sync is not needed, only move (overwrite if it exists). I think my main problem is the number of files, not the total size. The best way should be the way with less system calls per file to the NFS folders.

I tried cp, rsync, and finally http://moo.nac.uci.edu/~hjm/parsync/ parsync first took 10 hours in generate 12 GB gzip of the file list, after it took 40 hours and no one file was copied, it was working to 10 threads until I canceled it and started debugging, I found it is doing a call (stat ?) again to each file (from the list) with the -vvv option (it uses rsync):

```
[sender] make_file(accounts/hostingfacil/snap.2017-01-07.041721/hostingfacil/homedir/public_html/members/vendor/composer/62ebc48e/vendor/whmcs/whmcs-foundation/lib/Domains/DomainLookup/Provider.php,*,0)*
```

the parsync command is:

```
 time parsync  --rsyncopts="-v -v -v" --reusecache --NP=10 --startdir=/nfsbackup/folder1/subfolder2 thefolder /nfsbackup2/folder1/subfolder2
```

Each rsync has this form:

```
rsync --bwlimit=1000000 -v -v -v -a --files-from=/root/.parsync/kds-chunk-9 /nfsbackup/folder1/subfolder2 /nfsbackup2/folder1/subfolder2
```

The NFS folders are mounted:

```
server:/export/folder/folder    /nfsbackup2   nfs      auto,noexec,noatime,nolock,bg,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800,nfsvers=3,vers=3 0 0
```

Any idea how to instruct the rsync to copy the files already in the list from the nfs to the nfs2 folder? Or any way to make this copy efficiently (one system call per file?)

Comment: I think optimizing the movement of millions of file between two NFS mounts might be an interesting challenge but I would expect that development effort vs. speedup will be better when considering a change to the architecture to reduce the number of files and/or get rid of NFS.

Comment: @mnagel The NFS is provided by the datacenter as a backup service. The number of files is product of a incremental backup with 30 days retention of 450+ Hosting accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues doing the same once and I found that it's best to just run a find command and move each file individually.

```
cd /origin/path
find . | cpio -updm ../destination/
```

> -u command will override the existing files

Comment: Can you give a bit more of information? The below command will execute a cp per each file, una cp at once, right? and if need create directories will do it?

Comment: Is there is a directory structure attached with the 90Mil Files?

Comment: The files are inside a directory structure. There aren't 90 million files in a single folder.

Comment: If I understand well the command it will expand to

cpio -updm ../destination/ file1 /folder/file2 /folder/folder/file3

cp takes the last path as destination, isn't it?

Comment: That would put 90 million paths in arguments, it can't be.

Comment: No, I misunderstood, it will run the whole thing one file at a time. like cpio -udm /file1 /destinationpath/

Comment: Also you are sending the output of find to STDIN of cp in "man cp" I couldn't find any references to cp taking arguments from STDIN. (I was putting the print -0 with xargs -print0 in my mind)

Comment: yes, that's how it works. It's not just cp, you can do with with almost all the commands :) like setting a password with `echo "user:pass" | chpasswd`

Comment: If you read "man chpasswd" you will find: ".. user name and password pairs from standard input and uses this information .." standard input = STDIN, it depends how was programmed, there is not an standard to accept argv in STDIN too.

Comment: ah, but I use this all the time and it does work for me. You can try with some sample directories

Comment: I contacted the parsync developer, he is a university professor with good understanding about moving large data volumes. He explain there is not a optimimal solution to move million of files between NFS folders. So, I decided to took the best approach by using the already file list generated by parsync I'm executing the copy in this way:

cd /nfsbackup/folder/folder/
time cpio -p -duv /nfsbackup2/folder/folder/ < ~/.parsync/kds-chunk-1 &
All the 10 chunks in a concurrent way.

I won't post this as an answer because it copies between 1 and 4 Mb/s in a network of 1 Gb/s, no the best option